# Yeoman Webapp Installation fails on Windows 7 (also any other generator)

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

please help me out, because either yeomanm, npm or node sucks again... one of these and I don't know who. I've used yeoman in the past successfully, therefore I don't even know where the problem lies. Please help me debug my machine.

I have:

npm 1.4.28
node v0.10.32
yo 1.3.2
yo-webapp (latest version)
windows 7

And this is what actually happens:

```
 D:\wamp\www\test1>yo webapp

     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

Out of the box I include HTML5 Boilerplate, jQuery, and a Gruntfile.js to build your app.
? What more would you like? Bootstrap, Sass
? Would you like to use libsass? Read up more at
https://github.com/andrew/node-sass#node-sass: Yes
   create Gruntfile.js
   create package.json
   create .gitignore
   create .gitattributes
   create .bowerrc
   create bower.json
   create .jshintrc
   create .editorconfig
   create app\styles\main.scss
   create app\favicon.ico
   create app\robots.txt
   create app\index.html
   create app\scripts\main.js
   invoke   mocha


I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


   create     test\bower.json
   create     test\.bowerrc
   create     test\spec\test.js
   create     test\index.html
bower mocha#~1.14.0             cached git://github.com/visionmedia/mocha.git#1.14.0
bower mocha#~1.14.0           validate 1.14.0 against git://github.com/visionmedia/mocha.git#~1.14.0
bower bootstrap-sass-official#~3.2.0           cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.git#3.2.0+2
bower bootstrap-sass-official#~3.2.0         validate 3.2.0+2 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.git#~3.2.0
bower chai#~1.8.0               cached git://github.com/chaijs/chai.git#1.8.1
bower chai#~1.8.0             validate 1.8.1 against git://github.com/chaijs/chai.git#~1.8.0
bower jquery#>= 1.9.0                          cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.1
bower jquery#>= 1.9.0                        validate 2.1.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.9.0
bower chai#~1.8.0              install chai#1.8.1
bower mocha#~1.14.0            install mocha#1.14.0

chai#1.8.1 bower_components\chai

mocha#1.14.0 bower_components\mocha
bower bootstrap-sass-official#~3.2.0          install bootstrap-sass-official#3.2.0+2
bower jquery#>= 1.9.0                         install jquery#2.1.1

bootstrap-sass-official#3.2.0+2 bower_components\bootstrap-sass-official
└── jquery#2.1.1

jquery#2.1.1 bower_components\jquery
npm WARN package.json test1@ No description
npm WARN package.json test1@ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json test1@ No README data
\


> phantomjs@1.9.11 install D:\wamp\www\test1\node_modules\grunt-mocha\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs
> node install.js

Download already available at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows.zip
Extracting zip contents
Removing D:\wamp\www\test1\node_modules\grunt-mocha\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
Copying extracted folder C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows.zip-extract-1413800213030\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows -> D:\wamp\www\test1\node_modules\grunt-mocha\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
Removing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows.zip-extract-1413800213030
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at D:\wamp\www\test1\node_modules\grunt-mocha\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe
\


> node-sass@0.9.3 install D:\wamp\www\test1\node_modules\grunt-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node build.js

`win32-ia32-v8-3.14` exists; testing
|
..........\

  24 passing (159ms)

Binary is fine; exiting
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-jpegtran@1.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-gifsicle@1.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-optipng@1.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-pngquant@1.0.2
npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\56a4390f-m-cache-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\56a4390f-m-cache-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd D:\wamp\www\test1\test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\56a4390f-m-cache-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Why can't I install a generator anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is a cache lock file, try execute `npm cache clean` and install again.